# Flutter & Realm - How to rollback or commit a realm delete function

Tags: flutter, realm, commit, rollback

In Flutter, I add items to a list and save it to a local Realm. If I swipe on an item I am able to delete the item by running:

"realm.write(() => realm.delete(subscription));"

This works perfectly.

I have a snackbar that is displayed for 3 seconds after the swipe action and it has an UNDO button.

I would like to start a transaction to delete the item, but if the snackbar UNDO button is pressed then I would like to rollback the transaction. If the UNDO button is not pressed within the 3 seconds then I would like to commit the transaction.

I can't seem to find the commit/rollback logic for flutter/dart and realm.

Also open to run the delete function only if the UNDO button was not pressed. Just not sure where that code would be called.

```
void _removeItem(Subscriptionmodel subscription) {
    final subscriptionIndex = _registeredSubscriptions.indexOf(subscription);
    setState(() {
      _registeredSubscriptions.remove(subscription);
      _registeredSubscriptions_due.remove(subscription);
      realm.write(() => realm.delete(subscription)); **// Start Delete transaction - How????**        
    });

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
      content: const Text('Subscription deleted.'),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Undo',
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _registeredSubscriptions.insert(subscriptionIndex, subscription); 
            **//Rollback transaction here if Snackbar UNDO button is pressed**          
          });
        
        },        
      ),
    ));
 **//Commit transaction only if Snackbar button is not pressed - Not sure where the Commit line of code would go???? **
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just be a matter of; when the user swipes, remove the object from the UI only, but track the item as a soft delete (just store it in a var). After 3 seconds, remove it from Realm, nil the var. If they undo, then cancel the timer and restore the item in the UI from the var.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, the timer worked perfectly.